# Move Cursor Right When Typing ')' and Character Under Cursor is ')'

Tags: vim

I'm trying to use a combination of vim settings in .vimrc and vim functions to make the cursor move to the right when I type ')' IF there is already a ')'. What I've tried so far is adding the following to my .vimrc file:

`inoremap )   <Esc>:source PATH/TO/Function.vim<Enter>`

Where `Function.vim` is something like

```
if getline('.')[col('.')] == ')'
    " move cursor two spaces right and re-enter insert mode
else
    " move cursor one space right, enter insert mode, type ')'
endif
```

What commands can I use to manipulate the cursor from a .vim script file? Should I be using a different method entirely? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure this is a duplicate.

It's all about cursor position. A minus 1 offset is required as cursor position starts at 1 while string indices start at 0. And also `:imap-<expr>` to make it simple as there is no cursor teleportation, and also `i_CTRL-G_U` to make the mapping reoable. In the end, this is what all bracketing plugins do, here is [mine](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets).

```
inoremap <silent><expr> ) getline('.')[col('.')-1] == ')' ? '<c-g>U<right>' : ')'
```

PS: you certainly don't want to source a file here. It would be quite overkill and in some unfortunate conditions extremely slow.

Comment: You are pretty *rapide*, Luc!

Comment: @Biggybi and yet I've searched for a few minutes when was the last time I gave this exact same vimscript code. :) In the end I gave up. :(

Comment: Found it, it was on [r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/gk93pd/automate_brackets/fqrd6gf/?context=3)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
inoremap <expr> ) getline('.')[col('.')-1]==')' ? '<c-g>U<right>' : ')'
```

The `<expr>` tag tells vim to map `)` to the result of the right-hand side expression. Here, if the symbol under the cursor is a `(`, it will be `<right>`, else it will print a `)`.